# How to call function properties from other file

Tags: python, tkinter

There are 2 Files 1.Frontend 2.Backend
In Frontend There is one function pop(), which basically is b = a.get()
and what i want is whenever user type something in entry box it should be printed via backend...

## FRONTEND

```
from tkinter import *
import backend

win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")


def pop():
    b = a.get()

But = Button(text = "CLICK",command = pop)
But.pack()

a = StringVar()
e_1 = Entry(textvariable = a)
e_1.pack()
```

## BACKEND

```
from frontend import pop

print(b)
```

I was expected that whenever use type something in entry box it should be print via backend but i got an error that is "b" is not define..

Comment: variables defined in a function are only part of that function's "scope"

Comment: `b` is just a var used internally by `pop`, and you just imported `pop`, you never actually used it.

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Change pop to:

```
def pop():
    b = a.get()
    return b
```

Backend:

```
from frontend import pop
print(pop())
```

This prints b. 
Variables are defined in a function are only part of that function's "scope" as JacobIRR said, but you can still return the variable.